# CopyTo Method doesn't capture the Alt Text Titles from my Spreadsheet using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a code that deletes sheet and copies sheet from another Spreadsheet to another. However, the source spreadsheet I have copied contains an images with Alt Text titles on it. When I tried to copy it to my destination file, the Alt Text titles are not captured.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Thanks

```
function deleteAndReplaceSheet() {
  var masterConfigSheetId = 'xxxxxxx';
  var replicatedCardsFolderId = 'xxxxxxx';
  var masterSheetName = 'Mastersheet'
  var cardSheetName = "Card";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterConfigSheetId);
  var masterSheetReference = ss.getSheetByName(masterSheetName);
  var replicatedCards = DriveApp.getFolderById(replicatedCardsFolderId).getFiles();

  var employeeNumbers = masterSheetReference.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var employeeNumbersTrunc = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < employeeNumbers.length; i++){
    if(employeeNumbers[i][0] != "")
      employeeNumbersTrunc.push("" + employeeNumbers[i][0]);
    //    Logger.log(employeeNumbersTrunc);
  }

  while (replicatedCards.hasNext()) {
    var file = replicatedCards.next();
//    Logger.log(file);

    //check if employee number is existing inside the gdrive folder
    if (employeeNumbersTrunc.indexOf(file.getName())==-1) {
      continue;

    }
    try {      
      var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);

      var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
      var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxx');
      var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];

      var toBeDeletedSheet = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Card');

      //delete card sheetname
      activeSpreadSheet.deleteSheet(toBeDeletedSheet);
      sheet.copyTo(destination).setName('Card');
      destination.moveActiveSheet(2);

    } catch(err) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If "Alt Text titles" in your question is the value retrieved by [`getAltTextTitle()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#getalttexttitle), when the sheet is copied by `copyTo()`, the images with the alt text title are copied, and those can be also seen at the destination Spreadsheet. So in order to confirm your issue, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating it? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Thanks for your quick response as always. Unfortunately, we can't share files in our company because of the sharing restrictions we have.

But you can try this one if you can access it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xn0vBgaSmSRZGs4zxh0JtcMvCQt1CyB3ZxFtNwsm1U0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tanaike i'm not sure why Alt Text Titles are not included on the copyTo in my destination Spreadsheet. Is this a limitation of the copyTo?

Can you replicate this scenario on your end?

1. manual insert image in a cell in a spreadsheet.
2. Set alt text title
3. Make a copy of that sheet into another new spreadsheet.

Let's see it will work for you. Thanks

Comment: @Tanaike Can't give you access. this it is showing


This email address is linked to a personal Google Account. Company doesn't allow sharing with personal accounts.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when the sheet is copied by `copyTo()`, the images with the alt text title are copied, and those can be also seen at the destination Spreadsheet. So I thought that I would like to confirm your situation. But I understood that in your environment, you cannot provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue. So when I could replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. I tried to manually make a copy of the spreadsheet. The new copy of my spreadsheet still didn't capture the alt text of image from my original file. So I would assume that this is a limitation of copyTo method I think.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not possible. Since inserting images in cells is still a new feature in Google Sheets, the `.copyTo()` method doesn't support copying the `Alt Text Titles`.

I suggest you file a **feature request** at **Google Issue Tracker**  at this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917).